# Array data has unexpected data every other frame

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Console log

[image]

My list is adding the sprite name and converting it to an integer to add to a list, then I created a function to show the list but whenever I show the list in the update loop, it alternates between showing just 0's

and actual values. and when I don't put it in an update loop it only shows 0's

```
public class ballMove : MonoBehaviour {

int[] BallOrder = new int[5]; // me initializing the variable in the 
beginning of the program

// int[] BallOrder = {4,6,3,2,7}; if I do this instead of showing 0's it 
shows 4,6,3,2,7 when I click the mouse down.

void CreateBalls(int HowMany) {
// makes balls with a unique picture size and position
for (int i = 0; i < HowMany; i++) {
        BallClone = Instantiate(Ball);

        BallPic = BallClone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        // give each ball a random image, each image is a number
        RandImg(); 
        // just using i for testing purposes.        
        BallOrder[i] = i;
        //array should just be 1,2,3,4,5
    }
}

void ShowList() 
{
    System.Array.Sort(BallOrder);
    string text = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < BallOrder.Length; i++) 
    {
        text = (text + " " + BallOrder[i]);
    }
    
    print(text);
}

void Update()
{
    // here it shows the array correctly 1,2,3,4,5
    ShowList();
}
void OnMouseDown() {
    string BallNum = ConvertSprite(GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite);
    int test = int.Parse(BallNum);
    ShowList(); // here when I show list it just shows 0,0,0,0,0
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere else that you are calling `ShowList()`? How often and where are you parsing the `PicName` to grab the integers you are adding to this list? From the code, you posted it is hard to tell. I believe somewhere you are overwriting the existing list with all 0s. Can you add some more context to how and where you are setting the array `BallOrder`?

Comment: The only time I'm using showList is in the Update loop. I will edit my post to add more context and hope it can help. Btw this is my first time using this so I won't be professional at this. Basically I am converting the sprite image to a string, then the string to an interger and then adding to the list.

Comment: It's fine to be new. Generally, all code should be typed out and placed in the question, not sent as an image.

Comment: As it is printing twice, I would have to guess you have this script in two places in your project either on the same gameObject or on different objects. My other thought is something with how you are grabbing the substring of the name is doing something wonky. The line `test.Substring(0,2)`, are all name numbers at least this long? Or are some shorter?

Comment: the test.SUbstring(0,2) is basically removing the UnityEngine.text each sprite has, this means that every number will be "15" or "1 " with an empty space, it's not the most efficient but it's good for now, I'll change it once I get the list working.  I have the script attached to the game object and a textbox, so should I detach the strip from one?

Comment: Yes, that is what is causing the two prints possibly. As you have 1 printing proper numbers and another printing all zeroes. I am not sure which one is wrong, but most likely the one that has no data attached to it.

Comment: I detached it from a script and it is showing correctly, Thanks for your help dude :).

Comment: so my issue now is that when I put the showList in the update loop it shows it correctly, but when I put it anywhere else it just show's 0's.  so is it the way I use test.Substring(0,2)? Also I put a int[] BallOrder = new int[10]; at the beginning of my program, did I do it incorrectly? I only put [10] because I didn't know what to put it at.

Comment: Where else are you placing it? It has to be after your `Start` function as it is initializing the data.

Comment: I put it after the public class ballMove : MonoBehaviour  line

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific. That is just the declaration of your class that inherits from MonoBehaviour. Can you attach code or a photo of you are adding it?

Comment: I edited it and that's where I initialize the variable. not sure if you were looking for something else though

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. Where did you move the `ShowList` to? Does it only work in `Update`? Where did you move it to?

Comment: I moved it to a OnMouseDown() function, it gives me an error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" this happens when I try to do an if statement and it doesn't involve the gameobject, my edited post should help explaining what I mean. Basically I'm seeing if my image name matches with the current item on the array. Otherwise the array is just fine other than that hiccup

Comment: Right, so a null reference exception just means that there is some object that is not assigned. It can either be the `GetComponent` with the `SpriteRenderer`, but I believe it is the `BallOrder[0]`. It means that `BallOrder` is null when you are clicking which means it is not initialized.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I didn't put a new int[] and it caused an issue. However when I do print(BallOrder[0]) it prints out 0, keep in mind this is outside of the update loop so is that the issue? when I also print out the list it always has 5 zeroes which I put when I first initialize it, as in int[] BallOrder = new int[5]

Comment: That is because an integer's default value is 0. It means that the data is not set yet.

Comment: oh, so how do I set the data in? I already added the items to the list so I'm not sure how I set the data in to be used outside of the update loop.

Comment: There is initializing a data structure, which is something like `int[] BallOrder = new int[5]`. It means you want an array of type integer with a size of 5. What this looks like at default is {0, 0 ,0, 0, 0}. Now that the size is initialized though, you can access any of the indexes from 0 -> 4 and assign them. So with a line such as BallOrder[0] = 5, the array becomes {5, 0, 0, 0, 0}. You do not need to set these values in `Update`, but they need to be set at some point.

Comment: ah got it, I assigned the value during the Start function before the game starts. when I run the ShowList(); function in the update loop it shows fine but on the mouseclick function it shows 5 zeroes, I believe I posted some pictures of me assigning each array index a value.

Comment: Yes, but if you reset the data structure by using `BallOrder = new int[5]`, it will clear the values again.

Comment: hmmm, how should I get around this then?. if I replace int[] BallOrder = new int[5] with int[] BallOrder = {5,6,2,1,6,} then it will only display 5 6 2 1 6 instead of just 0's. the only other time I use new int[] was when creating new balls and assigned new values to the array and the list shows just fine on the update loop.

Comment: To be honest it is very hard to debug your code when it is all images. You need to just initialize the array once, then set it once. In the order of initialize -> set -> display. If anything is out of order, you will get errors or will get 0s.

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) ... you log beein always alternating between 0000 and actual values looks like there are **two** instances of that component in your scene and only one is initialized ... you should use `Debug.Log(text, this);` to be able to click on a log message and it will highlight the according object in your hierarchy

Comment: I figured out why I got the multiple zeroes and I detached the script from a textbox I forgot I linked it too. So my issue now is that when I use the update loop it shows the correct values, but on the mouse click event it doesn't. I'll edit my post and won't use images other then the console log and hope debugging is easier. Sorry for the post being unprofessional

Comment: I edited my post to not have photos and just lines of code, I cut out a lot of irrelevant code which don't contribute to my issue as they don't use the list in any way shape or form. Hopefully my problem is easier to debug. I simplified my code to have the array 1,2,3,4,5 as it still has the same problem of displaying incorrectly.

Comment: Where do you call the Update() function that works correctly? In place of ShowList() in MouseDown()? And why do you it the 'update loop' when there is no loop in Update()?

Comment: I put the update function under the start function, the showlist and mouse down are separate functions. Not sure if it answers your question though. Idk if update loop is the right word, all I know is that unity goes through the function every frame and think update loop is the right word.

Comment: Just FIY there is `print(string.Join(" ", BallOrder));` doing your loop Inna single line and way more efficient ;)

Comment: oh thanks for letting me know, unfortunately I still have the array showing the wrong values when it's outside the update loop, I guess I have to incorporate it in the update loop or something

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an answer to the question that is not in comments, the issue was that the console was printing out what could be considered bad data.

By alternating between what was expected (6 random numbers) and not expected (6 zeroes), clearly, the function was being called twice, but from further additions of code snippets, there was no reason as to why the function would be called multiple times.

From the initialization of the array data, the only way for there to be 6 zeroes instead of data was that the data was being overwritten or that it was never initialized. As the array is never written to again after the initialization, it must have meant that it was initialized incorrectly.

The only way for this to have occurred is by having the script attached to two objects in the scene where one is properly initializing the data and the other is not as the initialization occurred in `Start`.

The solution is to remove the unused script from one of the two objects in the scene.